# 32 bit oracle client in 64 bit application

Tags: oracle11g, 32bit-64bit, odp.net

Is this possible, create a .Net 3.5 Dll(A.dll), reference to Oracle 11g 32 bit client Oracle.DataAccess.dll. this dll will be used in another dll(B.dll), which load in AutoCAD 64 bit application. 32 bit version of AutoCAD is not allowed to install on Windows 7 64 bit. 
  Right now I set my B.dll as 'Any CPU', and A.dll as 'Any CPU' as well. 
  Do I have to use 64 bit oracle client in my A.dll? if not, how I can make it works?

Thank you
Wes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the 64-bit version of Oracle, yes. Mixing bit wideness (gonna trademark this term one day...) is unsupported by your operating system, there's nothing the .net framework can do about it.